# Groupby funciton in Python to output weighed survey value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to produce a weighted value of the following variable:

```
df.satisfaction.value_counts()

Satisfied 74
Dissatified 33
Don't know 4
Name: satisfaction, dtype: int64
```

I've used the groupby function as follows:

```
df.groupby('satisfaction').agg('sum')
```

However, this outputs all of the variables. Is there a way of selecting just the weight variable?

Or is there an alternative that I should know about?

Thanks.

Comment: `df.groupby('satisfaction')['weight'].sum()`?

Comment: Looks good, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This method seems to work: df.groupby('satisfaction')['weight'].sum()